# A good and comprehensive book on number theory and group theory

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, book-recommendation, advice

I am looking for a comprehensive and introductory (lot of examples, exercises) book that deals with topics like group theory, Dirichlet characters etc.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hey! Your ban duration is officially over. Glad to have you back, Enzo :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*.